# localhost 403 Forbidden PHP

Tags: php, apache, server

Read almost all questions here, but no solution found. This drives me crazy already to do such simple stuff to run PHP on my localhost...

> You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to
> read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user user   51 sep 27 14:42 .htaccess

ls -l
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user      4096 sep 27 15:17  www

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is an .htaccess file inside the www folder (and its permissions), since Apache looks for one at every directory up to the one where the requested file exists.

Comment: It is there: $ ls -a www
.  ..  .htaccess
And permissions are in my original post

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from an Apache on Windows server background, but in regards to the .htaccess file, you can also put a "AllowOverride None" in your  section of your httpd.conf file. At least in Windows, this means nothing can be overridden, therefore no need to look for .htaccess files.
You can also add a line to tell Apache that the "AccessFileName" is blank. Here are the entried I'm speaking of from my config file. I'm running a XAMPP server on Windows.

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName ""
```